# How to align this asp:TextBox with the other divs

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to create a calendar control with a precious day and next day button on each side of the textbox. [image: This is what it currently looks like]

All items are already in a table. All I really need to do is move the textbox down 1px and everything would be inline.

HTML:

I have tried inline-block, inline, position. I would really like advice.

```css
#scheduleNextDay {
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../../images/iconRight.png);
  padding: 4px 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #adadad;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#scheduleNextDay:hover {
  border: solid 1px #787878;
  background-color: #ececec;
  border-left: none;
}
#schedulePrevDay {
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../../images/iconLeft.png);
  padding: 4px 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #adadad;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#txtDate {
  float: left;
  border-top: solid 1px #adadad;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #adadad;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: super;
}
#table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#schedulePrevDay:hover {
  border: solid 1px #787878;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 0px;">
  <table id="table" : cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr align="center" valign="middle">
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" valign="middle">
        <div id="schedulePrevDay" title="Previous Day" class="borderRad_3Left">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" valign="middle">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="compactDate" MaxLength="10" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" valign="middle">
        <div id="scheduleNextDay" title="Next Day" class="borderRad_3Right">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
```

Comment: you have a lot of inline styling there, buddy. You should consider removing that and placing it with the other css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just adding a margin-top:1px; on the textbox, or padding-top:1px; on the table cell?